# Python code to append text to the first occurrence of new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried something like this and It doesn't work

```py
counter = 0
with open('tmp.txt','a') as file:
    while(counter == 0):
        if file.readline() == "\n":
            file.write("HI")
            file.write("\n")
            counter = 1
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Following is the content of the text file.

```
1
2
3
4

5
6
7
8
9

0
```

How do I append text to the *first occurrence of newline* in the file and then add a new line

Comment: Notice that the whole use of `counter` is not necessary. It is the same as just doing `while True` and `break`ing in the `if` (As you do anyway...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change the file while reading it. Instead read, change the file and write again:

```
with open('tmp.txt') as file:
  content = file.read()

new_content = content.replace('\n\n', f'\nHello\n',1)
with open('tmp.txt','w') as file:
  file.write(new_content)
```

Comment: I like your optimisation there, a good example of why planning before doing is important